# Do I need nomodify set on NTP servers which are not publicly accessible?

Tags: ntp

I am configuring five new RHEL6 NTP servers. Each uses a list of five USNO servers as their source with at least one unique server one each one. Each of the five servers also peers to the others. None of them is publicly accessible.

I'm not entirely sure of what my `restrict` line(s) should look like. Do I want to remove the `nomodify` option so the peers can update each other? I don't have the `nopeer` option as that would obviously be counter to the whole peering configuration. Do I want `nomodify` as a catch-all and have specific `restrict` lines without it for each of the peers?

ntp.conf from the first of the five:

```
restrict default kod notrap
restrict 127.0.0.1

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
logfile /var/log/ntp.log

server tick.usno.navy.mil iburst
server ntp-s1.cise.ufl.edu iburst
server ntp.colby.edu iburst
server navobs1.oar.net iburst
server gnomon.cc.columbia.edu iburst

broadcast 10.153.156.127 autokey

peer local-ntp-server.2 iburst autokey
peer local-ntp-server.3 iburst autokey
peer local-ntp-server.4 iburst autokey
peer local-ntp-server.5 iburst autokey

crypto
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keysdir /etc/ntp/crypto/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nomodify has nothing to do with server synchronization. `nomodify` has to do with changing settings on the server with ntpq/ntpdc. From the ntp access restriction documentation:

```
nomodify
    Deny ntpq and ntpdc queries which attempt to modify the state of the server
    (i.e., run time reconfiguration). Queries which return information are permitted.
```

http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/accopt.html

Why use 5 stratum one servers across five peers? Surely you could get by with 3 USNO servers and two servers from pool.ntp.org?

Comment: `Surely you could get by with 3 USNO servers and two servers from pool.ntp.org?` Design requirements.

Comment: If you need to utilize 10 off site USNO S1 servers you should look into putting a GPSDO on the LAN.

Comment: Not an option. We are in a hosted environment with very convoluted hardware ownership rules. Getting authorization to both purchase and install such hardware is essentially a non-starter.

Comment: Any decent data center should have an on site S1

Comment: Yup, they should and probably do. Unfortunately, the way the contract is set up we are in a very delicate position of not relying on the DC too much. It is a fine line between keeping us on as the support and handing everything over to the DC thereby putting us out of a job. Also, in the past, for some reason the DC didn't let us use their NTP source. Don't know why. Again, the rules are very convoluted.